# DB2 SQL Using a set of clauses from this years sales to find out what the Client purchased last year

Tags: sql, db2

DB2 SQL Using a set of clauses I am getting a result of specific deals.

Now I am trying to (using a where exists) look at the same table and matching the Part_num, Customer_Name and Date(Date - 1 year) to get the previous years sales for the same parts/Cust.

My end result if just to give me those previous years deals where the Customer number and part match this years sales. I cannot seem to get it to work but I suspect there maybe an easier way.

```
Select Part_Num, Customer_Num,Start_Date, End_Date 
from TableA
Where SalesNumber = A
)as A

WHERE (EXISTS
        (

SELECT Part_Num, Customer_Num,Start_Date, End_Date from Table A )AS B

where B.Part_Num = A.PArt_num and B.Customer_Num = A.Customer_Num and date(A.Start_date) = year(B.Start_Date - 1 year)
```

I am sure I have it wrong.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Desired result based of matching the Client_Number and Part_Num  using special sales number 'DOG'  give me all previous sales of that match Customer_num AND Part_number from the prev year

example if I had Client "XYZ" and they bought '123' under Sales Number "DOG" in start_date Jan 2, 2017

I want to pull all Cust who bought anything under Sales Number "DOG"

then I want to find out what those Clients paid for the exact same parts the previous year based off that Start_Date - 1 year

Answer (score 0):

Try this (but please try to make an effort next time...):

```
SELECT Part_Num
    ,Customer_Num
    ,Start_Date
    ,End_Date
FROM TABLE A    
WHERE EXISTS (
            SELECT Part_Num
                ,Customer_Num
                ,Start_Date
                ,End_Date
            FROM TABLE B 
            WHERE B.Part_Num = A.PArt_num
            AND B.Customer_Num = A.Customer_Num
            AND YEAR(A.Start_date) = YEAR(B.Start_Date) - 1 )
```

Comment: Thanks and appreciate the feedback, I have tried many different varioations (plus I am new to all of this) and maybe missed this configuration ran it and got  Message: Read timed out. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001